# PDO mysql query statement issue

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I tried the request

```
DB::query('INSERT INTO users VALUES (\'\', :nom, :prenom, :pseudo, :birthdate, :level, :classroom, :contactNumber1, :contactNumber2,:pathphoto, :schoolName, :password, :email, :town, :registerDate)',
  array(':nom'=>'',
  ':prenom'=>'', 
  ':pseudo'=>$username,
  ':birthdate'=>'',
  ':level'=>'',
  ':classroom'=>'',
  ':contactNumber1'=>'',
  ':contactNumber2'=>'',
  ':pathphoto'=>'',
  ':schoolName'=>'',
  ':password'=>$password,
  ':email'=>$email,
  ':town'=>'',
  ':registerDate'=>'')
);
```

but I got the error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException'
```

with message

```
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens' in C:\wamp64\www\mongbaki\social\classes\DB.php
```

I would like to know where the problem is.

Comment: Instead of fighting your quoting selection, why not use `"` instead? MySQL's default allows `""` in place of `''`.

Comment: (sorry for bad english) I can asume that `\'\', ` is for an ID, remove it and try again... if you don't provide and `id` field in binding array, you should not put `\'\'`

Comment: you have missed argument must passed to your array, not sure what is the `\'\'` doing in your first values elements

Comment: You should also specify which columns these are going into, though as there's a lot of them here that are left as defaults you could leave those out. Another thing to consider before you get too heavily invested in this method is to try using an ORM like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) or
[Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent) to wrap your database into something more concise.

Comment: I  tried "" but i get message SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

Comment: Seconding tadman's suggestion to include the fields inserted into as well; in my opinion they should be included in all but the simplest, most obvious cases (such as low field count temporary tables created and used immediately by the same code that spawned them).

Comment: DB::query('INSERT INTO users VALUES (:nom, :prenom, :pseudo, :birthdate, :level, :classroom, :contactNumber1, :contactNumber2,:pathphoto, :schoolName, :password, :email, :town, :registerDate)', array("","", ':pseudo'=>$username,"","","","","","","",':password'=>$password,':email'=>$email,"",""));

Answer (score -1):

After troubleshooting I found my error.

```
DB::query('INSERT INTO users (nom, prenom, pseudo, birthdate, level, classroom, contactNumber1, contactNumber2, pathphoto, schoolName, password, email, town, registerDate) VALUES (:nom, :prenom, :pseudo, NOW(), :level, :classroom, :contactNumber1, :contactNumber2, :pathphoto, :schoolName, :password, :email, :town,  NOW())', array(':nom'=>"",':prenom'=>"", ':pseudo'=>$username,':level'=>"",':classroom'=>"",':contactNumber1'=>"",':contactNumber2'=>"",':pathphoto'=>"",':schoolName'=>"",':password'=>$password,':email'=>$email,':town'=>"" ));
```

Comment: ... and the error was? It is important for questions on stackoverflow to have a non-zero chance of being useful to someone else in the future.